# Autodesk forge get all objects with specific property from model derivative api

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Is there a way to fetch all the objects having a specific property
using   {urn}/metadata/{modelGuid}/properties:query
but without any query condition .

and is there a way to use the $contains condition and to include a string with space into the search ?

I tried to use the api but if i have a property with a string after the space character it is not being detected.

Comment: Unfortunately, /properties:query has not supported to get all objects without condition. I think you want to get properties in pagination, rather than whole json bulk with the other endpoint  /properties. We have raised the wish with engineering team

Comment: as to $contains, do you mean the value is like "   mystring"?  I am afraid the space will be ignored. We can also raise the wish.

Comment: Thank you for the reply , for the 1st part , yes i mean if i want to get for example all the objects having a property without querying the property value, for example property "description" and return all the objects paginated having this property defined. -for the second $contains , like " mystring" or for example to find substring if exist in property value having space like to find "he" in the following property values "hello"or "( he l l o)" or " h=>he" or "friend-he-hello"